# zkcli.sh: 13: zkcli.sh: unzip: not found

Tags: amazon-web-services, tomcat, solr, debian, apache-zookeeper

I've been trying to get Solr working on AWS for a few days now. I've been following this tutorial: [Tutorial for setting up SolrCloud on Amazon EC2](http://www.francelabs.com/blog/tutorial-solrcloud-amazon-ec2/)  and I almost have it but when I run this line in SSH:

```
sh zkcli.sh -zkhost ec2-xx-xxx-x-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181,ec2-xx-xx-x-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181,ec2-xx-xxx-xx-xx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:2181 -cmd upconfig -confdir /opt/solr_install/example/solr/collection1/conf -confname myconfig
```

I get the following error:

```
 zkcli.sh: 13: zkcli.sh: unzip: not found
    Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.solr.cloud.ZkCLI
```

I'm not sure how to proceed. Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the trouble. I had to install unzip i.e. `sudo apt-get install unzip`